# Is it possible to make an input not required with Slack API?

Tags: php, slack, slack-api

I'm building a Slack App feature with a modal and several inputs.

One of them is a static select with some options.

I would like to make it optionnal but it seems that there is no solution for that.

I tried to set `dispatch_action` to false but it is unrelated I believe.

Here is my input configuration :

```php
[
    'type' => 'input',
    'dispatch_action' => false,
    'label' => [
    'type' => 'plain_text',
        'text' => 'Choose an option (or not)',
    ],
    'element' => [
        'type' => 'static_select',
        'placeholder' => [
            'type' => 'plain_text',
            'text' => 'Choose an option',
        ],
        'options' => array_map(static function($data) {
            return [
                'text' => [
                    'type' => 'plain_text',
                    'text' => $data->name,
                ],
                'value' => (string) $data->id,
            ];
        }, $dataValues),
    ],
],
```

[image: I can't make this field not required]

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add "optional": true as property of input block.

> 'type' => 'input',
>
> **'optional': true,**
>
> 'dispatch_action' => false,

Comment: Thank you sir, I missed that config option !

Comment: Thank you! Do you know where this is documented? I don't see it anywhere in the docs for block elements

Comment: I couldn't find the specific documentation but if you check the example here, you can find it: https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#modal_response_url